# Change global tint color - iOS7/iOS8

Tags: ios7, uicolor, tintcolor

How can we change **the global tint color on iOS7/iOS8** by code? I want to change multiple objects that use this property, but not change each one, that's why I want to use the global tint property.

Comment: I know you specified "by code", still, I think it's important to mention there is a global tint property in the storyboard's file inspector

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Simply change the `UIWindow` 's `tintColor` in your application delegate, it's automatically passed as default to all its `UIView` descendants.

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: You're right, fairly simple just add _window.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor]; (autosynthesize) But can I change it from other view?

Comment: It's implemented on any `UIView` , so you can set it on any view in your views hierarchy, and all its descendants will inherit same default `tintColor` (unless you specify otherwise)

Comment: IMPORTANT: don't forget to test the selector for ios6 compatibility:  `if([window respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)])`

Comment: This method doesn't seem to propagate to navigation toolbars though.

Comment: any custom xibs are somehow not affected by both `UIWindow`'s `tintColor` property or the Global tint as suggested in another option. Setting the `UIView`'s appearance proxy for `tintColor` works.

Comment: You should use appearance protocol instead, as @carmen_munich explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19140595/514181

Answer (score 69):

`[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];`

Comment: If you need to tint UIAlertView buttons and not just the main app window this is that best answer!

Comment: `UIView`'s `tintColor` doesn't have the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` annotation. This answer is wrong.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer as it affect UIAlertView while the accepted answer is not.

Comment: @Tobol is technically correct. There is confusion around this and it really needs clarification from Apple. `UIAppearance` was introduced in iOS 5 as a way to handle global color (and more), but then in iOS 7 Apple moved `tintColor` to `UIView` and made it propagate  to subviews. In the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html) Apple states: "Setting the tintColor property by using the appearance proxy APIs is not supported in iOS 7." Yet it still seems to work.

Comment: Thank you Jamie. I think we should qualify this as an undefined behavior because it can change in future iOS releases without warning.

Comment: @Tobol nevertheless UIView conforms to UIAppearance and UIAppearanceContainer. For example the UIBarButtonItem tintColor has no UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR annotation as well

Comment: Alright, alert views are presented in their own window, separate from the app's (IIRC).

Comment: Important! This will affect buttons disabled color and other controls state color.

Comment: This breaks with certain `UIBarButtonItem`s, such as the "Done" item. Use with caution.

Answer (score 39):

There are two ways to change your global tint color. As many mentioned above you could change `self.window.tintColor` in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

More elegant way, in my opinion, is to set *Global Tint* in *File Inspector* in your Storyboard while nothing is selected. This way your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is cleaner.

[image: Global Tint in File Inspector]

Comment: any custom xibs are somehow not affected by both `UIWindow`'s `tintColor` property or the Global tint as you suggest.

Comment: not sure why changing storyboard option did not work, but `self.window?.tintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xc0392b)` did.

Comment: That would be amazing if Xcode was functional. Probably this will work on Xcode release 345. Today, as expected, Xcode craps on my head and do nothing. I wish Apple fires satan from the position of head of developer tools in the near future.

Comment: I feel you bro/sis.

Answer (score 12):

You can specify a tint color for the entire app by setting the window’s tint property. To do this, you could use code similar to the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Updated for Swift 2.2**

You can do this from anywhere like this:

```
// Get app delegate
let sharedApp = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

// Set tint color
sharedApp.delegate?.window??.tintColor = UIColor.green()
```

Or if you're trying to do this from AppDelegate,

```
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.green()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for Swift 5**

Write in the App Delegate :

```
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140595/2419581) but in Swift

Answer (score 0):

In modern UIScene based apps you must iterate through all windows from all scenes to set the `tintColor` for the whole running app, with code like this:

```
for scene in UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes {
    if let windows = (scene as? UIWindowScene)?.windows {
        for window in windows {
            window.tintColor = .green
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following things **DID NOT WORKED** for me:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR

navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR], for: .normal)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black

navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR

navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR

navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR]
```

**Following WORKED :**

1. SET THE GLOBAL TINT COLOR FROM STORYBOARD.

OR

2. SET THE TINT COLOR OF THE WINDOW

FOR WHOLE APP:

```
let sharedApp = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
sharedApp.delegate?.window??.tintColor = UIColor.green()
```

FOR SPECIFIC CONTROLLER:

set tint color of window while initialization and set back the default tint color of the app while deinitialization.

```
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        window?.tintColor = Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        window?.tintColor = Theme.light.healthKit.BACK_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR
    }

    deinit {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
        window?.tintColor = Theme.light.App.DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR
    }
```