# How to change UIDatePicker tint color?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am aware that UIDatePicker cannot be customized but I am wondering how in iOS 14 Reminders app shows blue tint and Calender shows red tint.

I set global tint color in AppDelegate to `.label` as below but unable to set the same for date picker.

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = .label
```

Is this possible?

Another issue I have observed is in dark mode current date’s day number isn’t visible. How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reminders** and **Calendar** have blue and red tint color (accent color)  respectively.

---

`UIView.appearance().tintColor = .label` works. However, the **.label** is white in darkmode and the text-color of today's date when selected is also white. Therefore, it looks so. Use another color than `.label` (white) to test it,

You can not change the text color of today's date. It is always white, I think.

You may not need to change the global tint color. If you only need to chagne the tintColor of the datepicker, do this:

`datepicker.tintColor  = .yourColor` does the job.

If your global tint color is `.label`, use another color than `.label` as the tint-color of `UIDatePicker` to fix the issue.

---

You can also change the global tint color using one of the following method.

#### UIKit

You need to change the tint color of the whole App to change the tint color of **UIDatePicker**.

```
    self.window?.tintColor = .primary // .red
```

- In `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`, use the above code
- If you do not use `SceneDelegate`, use the code above in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`
- You can also change it in Storyboard.

https://stephenradford.me/quick-tip-globally-changing-tint-color-application-wide/

---

#### SwiftUI

Change **accentColor** in **Assets**.

---

[Change global tint color - iOS7/iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960321/change-global-tint-color-ios7-ios8)

Comment: Thanks. I have now opted a different tint color globally. This helped with picker text color.