# iOS 14 datePicker - highlighted day in dark mode unreadable

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, ios14, darkmode

I'm having an issue using the inline datePicker on iOS 14. There  appearance is all good in light mode but in dark  mode I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the highlighted (today's) date is not visible due to white highlighting and white text colour.  Am I  missing  something here? Is this really Apple's  default design?

I cannot  find any  was to change the colour of  this highlighted date. I did try to remove the highlighting  at all:

```
datePicker.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")
```

But on iOS 14 this  crashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change UIDatePicker tint color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510069/how-to-change-uidatepicker-tint-color)

Comment: Sadly  tintColor is having no impact at all!

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Do you have a sample code for this functionality?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?