# Incorrect tint color DatePicker swift 5 ios16

Tags: xcode, swift5, uidatepicker

I'm using `UIDatePicker` with `preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline` and `tintColor = .systemOrange`. I've tried to put this settings inside ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear but the result is that the tint color remains blue. How can I solve?
Following an image of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510069/how-to-change-uidatepicker-tint-color

Comment: Tried but not works